# test Google Play Game Service Multiplayer with one account

Tags: android, google-play-games, google-account

I'm making a Multiplayer game using Google Play Game Service for connection. I'm at the point where I need to test connection between devices and it seem like I need a different account for each device.

I tried create new Google Account, but Google force me to verify account with a phone number that had not been used to verify another account. I only have one phone number.

The question is: How developer test their apps in this situation ? Do they have multiple phone number just for verify account ? (need to afford multiple phone bills just to keep them active ?)

Answer (score 0):

Some developer are using Android Emulator. Just download the emulator system image that includes the Google Play Services, under Android 4.2.2, from the SDK Manager. However, it is highly recommended to run your game on your physical test device.

Must verify that you have set up the test account that you are using to log in to the app. You don't need to have multiple account, just export an APK and sign it with the same '*certificate*' that you used to set up the project in Google Play Developer Console. Then, install the signed APK on the physical test device by using the adb tool.

For more information, use this as your reference: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#top_of_page